Meaning behind אישים plural
I've seen 3 places throughout tanach that use the plural אישים for men as opposed to אנשים.
Psalms 141:4
Proverbs 8:4
Isaiah 53:3
Is there any particular reason for this?
Also, why isn't this the plural form used in other places? It does seem more straightforward.

https://hebrew-academy.org.il/2021/05/06/%d7%90%d7%99%d7%a9-%d7%95%d7%90%d7%99%d7%a9%d7%94/
